# DataSet DataTable - WriteXml con Genericos

Tags: c#, wcf

DataSet y DataTable tienen el método "WriteXml". En mi código algunos procedimientos almacenados devuelven un DataSet y otros devuelven un DataTable, los cuales luego se deben pasar a una cadena con formato XML para luego publicarlo usando WCF.

Para evitar escribir 02 métodos (uno para el ds y otro para el dt), es posible/correcto realizar el siguiente código?, por favor deseo algunas sugerencias. Muy agradecido de antemano.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Convierte un objeto de tipo DataSet o DataTable en una repreentación de cadena  con formato Xml
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="dataObject"></param>
    /// <param name="encoding"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string DataToXmlString<T>(T dataObject, Encoding encoding) where T: new()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (dataObject == null)
            return result;
        else
        {
            XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings()
            {
                // OmitXmlDeclaration = true, // Omite: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                Encoding = encoding,
                ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document
            };

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlSettings))
                {
// Aquí es donde se hace la pregunta
                    if (dataObject is DataSet)
                        (dataObject as DataSet).WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
                    else if (dataObject is DataTable)
                        (dataObject as DataTable).WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

                    xmlWriter.Close();
                }
                result = encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Convierte una cadena con formato Xml, en un objeto de tipo T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> Tipo al que será convertido</typeparam>
    /// <param name="stringXmlData"></param>
    /// <param name="encoding"></param>
    /// <returns>Objeto dle tipo T</returns>
    public static T XmlStringToData<T>(this string stringXmlData, Encoding encoding)
    {
        T returnObject = default(T);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringXmlData)) return default(T);

        using (MemoryStream Xmlstream = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(stringXmlData)))
        {
            if (returnObject is DataSet)
                (returnObject as DataSet).ReadXml(Xmlstream, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
            else if (returnObject is DataTable)
                (returnObject as DataTable).ReadXml(Xmlstream);

            Xmlstream.Close();
        }
        return returnObject;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

utiliza dos métodos, para datatable usa el `MemoryStream` y para dataset es mas fácil usar el `dataset.ToXml();` no tires tanto código